# Using Remail gem with ruby on rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Have anyone made [Remail](https://github.com/maccman/remail) to work with Ruby on Rails. I am trying to set it up, but it 
throws `Errno::ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused - connect(2)):` while sending an email. I followed the instructions in the [this page](http://leadthinking.com/233-sending-or-receiving-emails-with-rails).

**environment.rb**

```
Emailsample::Application.configure do
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :remail
  config.action_mailer.remail_settings = {
    :app_id  => "my-gae-app-id",
    :api_key => "3d4f1a200e5811e081e00800200c9a66"
  }
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Rails 3, you shouldn't change the `environment.rb` file.
Write your configuration in the `application.rb` file instead.

Enter the following configurations in the `application.rb` file, within the `class Application < Rails::Application` section.

```
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :remail
config.action_mailer.remail_settings = {
  :app_id  => "my-gae-app-id",
  :api_key => "3d4f1a200e5811e081e00800200c9a66"
}
```

Also, make sure the Gem is listed in the `Gemfile` file and you run `bundle install`.